# I have to display all names one by one on textview please give solution

Tags: android

In my server side database 400000 college names are present and I have to display all names one by one simultaneously on single textview please give solution

Comment: You can use https://github.com/ahmadaghazadeh/EndlessRecyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code no one would be able to help you. But still I am gonna give you some idea on how you can do that.
As soon as you get some new record just append the text in `TextView`:

For first time :

```
textView.setText("record 1");
```

after that after getting each record:

```
textView.append(textView.getText() + "\n" + "record 2"); // and so on
```

Comment: If it helped you please accept this answer or ask any further query if you have